# Java Check String Variable Length (with Substring)

Tags: java, string, if-statement, substring, case

I have a String variable which can have a different length every time it runs.
With it, I check what it starts with, for example:

```
 public void defineLocation(){
            if (newLocation.substring(0,2).equals("DO") || newLocation.substring(0,2).equals("30") || newLocation.substring(0,2).equals("21")) {
                locationInDc = "DOOR";
            } else if (newLocation.substring(0,2).equals("VT") || newLocation.substring(0,3).equals("MUF")) {
                locationInDc = "BLOUBLOU";
            } else if (newLocation.substring(0,3).equals("MAH")) {
                locationInDc = "BLOBLO";           
            } else if (newLocation.substring(0,7).equals("Zone 72") || newLocation.substring(0,7).equals("Zone 70")){
                locationInDc = "BLOFBLOF";
}
```

I know this is not the most efficient way and it is bound to break as, if my variable is not in either of the first 3 checks but still has less characters than 7 then it will throw an error.

Is there a more "correct" way to do this? Should I check first how many characters the string contains and then point it to the right checks/"ifs"? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since all of your checks are testing the beginning of the String, use `startsWith` instead of combining `substring` and `equals` and you won't have to worry about `newLocation` being too short.

For example, replace

```
if (newLocation.substring(0,2).equals("DO") || newLocation.substring(0,2).equals("30") || newLocation.substring(0,2).equals("21"))
```

with

```
if (newLocation.startsWith ("DO") || newLocation.startsWith ("30") || newLocation.startsWith ("21"))
```

Comment: I don't understand why someone down voted it..!!! OP asked any other correct way to do this and this is it.

Comment: Well, Eran probably won't run out of points just yet, even with random downvotes.

Comment: startsWith! I just feel so silly right now... Thanks a lot

Comment: The other advantage of this is that it avoids creating new string objects for each comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Use string.startWith for the check and maybe use a Map for the mapping.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("DO", "DOOR");
map.put("30", "DOOR");
map.put("21", "DOOR");
map.put("VT", "BLOUBLOU");
map.put("MUF", "BLOUBLOU");
map.put("MAH", "BLOBLO");
map.put("Zone 72", "BLOFBLOF");
map.put("Zone 70", "BLOFBLOF");

for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (newLocation.startsWith(entry.getKey())) {
        locationInDc = entry.getValue();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea for the map, I ll do that! Thanks @ArticLord